# Splitting a Dataframe by columns and by row in R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
 P   sample    sensor1    sensor2    sensor3........sensorP
 a   1         2.45       3.56       2.345          2.33
 a   2         2.37       3.46       2.22           1.98
 a   3         2.78       3.22       1.45           2.67
 a   N
```

I want it to look like this:

```
P  1_sensor1   2_sensor1   3_sensor1......N_sensorn1    2_sensor1    2_sensor2    
a  2.45        2.37        2.78                         3.56         3.46
```

and so on....
So split the sensors horiszontally and split the samples within each horizonatally too.
I know its a reshape2 solution - I just can't get the syntax.
The Sensors will have different names and the sample length  can also vary...hence the N.

paul.

Comment: not really i want to split multiple cols with multiple samples this example doesn't do that

Comment: It does exactly that; your column `P` is analogous to their column `ID`, your column `sample` is analogous to `TIME`, `sensor1` to `X`, and `sensor2` to `Y`; it translates exactly to what you're doing. Assuming your data frame is named `df`, just try this: `dcast(melt(df, id.vars=c("P", "sample")), P~variable+sample)` -- which is the solution to the linked duplicate question -- and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: OK - I stand corrected, it worked exactly how I needed it...! Thanks for taking the time to re-explain.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with `tidyverse` package. Like this:

```
library(tidyverse)
data <- data.frame(sample = 1:4,
               sensor1 = rnorm(4, 2), 
               sensor2 = rnorm(4, 2), 
               sensor3 = rnorm(4, 2), 
               sensor4 = rnorm(4, 2))
data %>% 
  gather(sensor, value, sensor1:sensor4) %>%
  unite(names, sample, sensor) %>%
  spread(names, value)
```

The result is something like you are looking for:

```
  1_sensor1 1_sensor2 1_sensor3 1_sensor4 2_sensor1 2_sensor2 2_sensor3 2_sensor4
[1]  1.549545  3.166664 0.9557496  2.745318  2.246499  2.597675  3.352947  3.085531
  3_sensor1 3_sensor2 3_sensor3 3_sensor4 4_sensor1 4_sensor2 4_sensor3 4_sensor4
[1]  1.879149   3.82827   3.84254  3.052806  1.529147 0.6595416  1.286521  2.302484
```